# Swap Multiple file paths with same class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, responsive

I am trying to change the file path for an image depending on the width of the screen. I have gotten it to work so far as the file path does change but it ONLY affects the first element in the sense that it changes ALL file paths to the same one.

When I view my code in the browser both image 1 and image 2 are replaced with `src="Images/image.jpg"`. Could someone help me in identifying what I need to do/change in order for it to affect EVERY element with the class name "swap-image" uniquely?

As in, change

```
src="Images/image.jpg" 
src="Images/image1.jpg"
```

to

```
src="Images/tablet/image.jpg" 
src="Images/tablet/image1.jpg"
```

Thank you in advance.

```
<body>
    <img class="swap-image" src="Images/image.jpg" />
    <img class="swap-image" src="Images/image1.jpg" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var swapImageClass = document.getElementsByClassName("swap-image");
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < swapImageClass.length; i++) {

                var src = $(swapImageClass).attr('src'); // "Images/image.jpg"
                var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["static","Images","banner","image.jpg"]
                var file = tarr[tarr.length - 1]; // "image.jpg"
                var data = file.split('.')[0];  // "image"

                $(window).on('load resize', function () {
                    $(swapImageClass).each(function () {
                        if ($(window).width() > 1025) {
                            $(swapImageClass).attr('src', 'Images/' + file);
                        }
                        else if ($(window).width() > 481 && $(window).width() < 1024) {
                            $(swapImageClass).attr('src', 'Images/tablet/' + file);
                        }
                        else if ($(window).width() > 0 && $(window).width() < 480) {
                            $(swapImageClass).attr('src', 'Images/mobile/' + file);
                        }
                    });
                });
            };

        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

We base the filename on the current element in the loop and bind an eventlistener to it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var swapImageClass = $('.swap-image');

    swapImageClass.each(function(index) {
        var filename = $(this).attr('src').split('/').pop(),
            img = $(this);

        $(window).on('load resize', function() {
            var w = $(window).width();

            if (w > 1025) {
                img.attr('src', 'Images/' + filename);
            } else if (w > 481 && w < 1024) {
                img.attr('src', 'Images/tablet/' + filename);
            } else if (w > 0 && w < 480) {
                img.attr('src', 'Images/mobile/' + filename);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using jquery I think you can simply use class name and `each()` loop.

```
$(window).on('load resize', function () {
                $(".swap-image").each(function () {
                  var src = $(this).attr('src'); // "Images/image.jpg"
                        var tarr = src.split('/');      // ["static","Images","banner","image.jpg"]
                      var file = tarr[tarr.length - 1]; // "image.jpg"
                    if ($(window).width() > 1025) {
                        $(this).attr('src', 'Images/' + file);
                    }
                    else if ($(window).width() > 481 && $(window).width() < 1024) {
                        $(this).attr('src', 'Images/tablet/' + file);
                    }
                    else if ($(window).width() > 0 && $(window).width() < 480) {
                        $(this).attr('src', 'Images/mobile/' + file);
                    }
                });
            });
```

check this function here https://jsfiddle.net/7619099p/

Answer (score 0):

Just modifying your code here, was this the expected?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        //Here we are saving the file name as a data attribute to each images
        $(".swap-image").each(function(index, element) {
            var tarr = $(element).attr("src").split('/');
            var file = tarr[tarr.length - 1];
            $(element).data("filename",file);               
        });

        $(window).on('load resize', function () {
            $(".swap-image").each(function () {
             // and here we are using the saved data attribute(filename) for new path [$(this).data("filename")] on resize.This will give you individual new paths based on screen resolution.
                    if ($(window).width() > 1025) {
                        $(swapImageClass).attr('src', 'Images/' + $(this).data("filename"));
                    }
                    else if ($(window).width() > 481 && $(window).width() < 1024) {
                        $(swapImageClass).attr('src', 'Images/tablet/' + $(this).data("filename"));
                    }
                    else if ($(window).width() > 0 && $(window).width() < 480) {
                        $(swapImageClass).attr('src', 'Images/mobile/' + $(this).data("filename"));
                    }
                });
            });

    });
```